# MySQL delete statement with a pkID

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete a row from three tables in my DB. Each row has the same primary key and should be deleted when an html submit button is pushed.

Here is my code:

```
//Delete Every entry with pk = $id
 if(isset($_POST["butDelete"])){

     // minor security check
     if ($fromPage != $yourURL) {
         die("<p>Sorry you cannot access this page. Security breach detected and reported.</p>");
     }

     //Delete from tblUser
     $sql = "DELETE ";
     $sql .= "FROM tblUser ";
     $sql .= "WHERE pkID=" . $id;

     $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

     $stmt->execute();

     //Delete from tblPhoto
     $sql = "DELETE ";
     $sql .= "FROM tblPhoto ";
     $sql .= "WHERE pkID=" . $id;

     $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

     $stmt->execute();

     //Delete from tblAlbum
     $sql = "DELETE ";
     $sql .= "FROM tblAlbum ";
     $sql .= "WHERE pkID=" . $id;

     $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

     $stmt->execute();

 }
```

The code is currently not deleting any records and I am not sure why. At first I thought something might be wrong with the MySQL statement being created but I couldn't find any issues. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st.

Try to echo your $sql query and try to run it directly on phpMyAdmin to determine whether you only missed something from concatenating strings.

2nd.

If the ID is string then you are missing something like a single quote. Try something like this:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM tblName WHERE id = '".$pkID."'");
```

3rd.

Check if your code successfully connected to the database and if all privileges were set properly and accordingly.